# Need help in getting attribute to display in descending order (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am writing a oracle sql procedure to list out the customer orders for the first 10 customers. However, one of the requirements needed would be to output the attribute total price in descending order which I am unable to achieve. Instead the output is sorted by the order key instead. Any help in getting the output to sort by descending order for total price is desired. I also am trying to get the date to print out fully as so: 01-Nov-1995 instead of 01-Nov-95 as I am currently getting.

[Current Code]

```
set linesize 100
set pagesize 200
set serveroutput on
set line 256
--
-- Task 02
create or replace procedure showCustomerOrders is
  previousCustomer CUSTOMER.c_custkey%type := -1;
begin
  for currentRow IN (select c_custkey,
                            c_name,
                            o_custkey,
                            o_orderdate,
                            o_orderkey,
                            o_totalprice
                       from customer
                       left outer join orders
                         on c_custkey = o_custkey
                      where c_custkey in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
                      order by c_custkey,
                               c_name,
                               o_custkey,
                               o_orderkey,
                               o_orderdate,
                               o_totalprice DESC) loop
    if previousCustomer != currentRow.c_custkey then
      dbms_output.put_line(chr(10)); -- new line
      dbms_output.put_line(currentRow.c_custkey || ' - ' ||
                           currentRow.c_name || ':');
    end if;
    --
    if currentRow.o_custkey is not null then
      dbms_output.put_line(chr(9) ||
                           lpad(trim(to_char(currentRow.o_orderkey)), 12) || ', ' ||
                           lpad(trim(to_char(currentRow.o_orderdate)), 12) || ', ' ||
                           rpad(trim(to_char(currentRow.o_totalprice,
                                             '$999G999G999D99')),
                                14));
    end if;
    --
    previousCustomer := currentRow.c_custkey;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line(null);
end;
/
show error
```

[Current Output]

```
1 - Customer#000000001:
          385825,    01-NOV-95, $254,563.49
          430243,    24-DEC-94, $37,713.17
          454791,    19-APR-92, $78,172.70
          579908,    09-DEC-96, $43,874.94
         1071617,    10-MAR-95, $156,748.63
         1374019,    05-APR-92, $189,636.00
         1590469,    07-MAR-97, $59,936.41
         1755398,    12-JUN-97, $1,466.82
         1763205,    28-AUG-94, $18,112.74
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to rearrange your SQL statement such as

```
SELECT c_custkey, c_name, o_custkey, TO_CHAR(o_orderdate,'DD-Mon-YYYY') AS o_orderdate, 
       o_orderkey, o_totalprice
  FROM
  (
  SELECT c.*, o.*,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY o_totalprice DESC) AS dr       
    FROM customer c
    LEFT JOIN orders o
      ON c_custkey = o_custkey
   )   
 ORDER BY dr
```

where you only need `o_totalprice` column within `ORDER BY` list.

If the version of DBMS is `12+`, then directly use the analytic function within `ORDER BY` list :

```
SELECT c_custkey, c_name, o_custkey, TO_CHAR(o_orderdate,'DD-Mon-YYYY') AS o_orderdate,  
       o_orderkey, o_totalprice
  FROM customer c
  LEFT JOIN orders o
    ON c_custkey = o_custkey
 ORDER BY DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY o_totalprice DESC) 
 FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Thx alot for the help! It has been really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure showCustomerOrders is 
previousCustomer CUSTOMER.c_custkey%type := -1;
begin
  for currentRow IN (select c_custkey, c_name, o_custkey, o_orderdate, o_orderkey, o_totalprice
            from customer left outer join  orders
                on c_custkey = o_custkey
            where c_custkey in
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
order by 
o_totalprice DESC,
c_custkey, 
c_name, 
o_custkey, 
o_orderkey,
o_orderdate)
  loop
    if previousCustomer != currentRow.c_custkey then
    dbms_output.put_line( chr(10) ); -- new line
    dbms_output.put_line(currentRow.c_custkey || ' - ' || currentRow.c_name||':');
    end if;
--
    if currentRow.o_custkey is not null then
    dbms_output.put_line (chr(9)||lpad(trim(to_char(currentRow.o_orderkey)),12)||', '
||lpad(trim(to_char(currentRow.o_orderdate)),12)||', '
        ||rpad(trim(to_char(currentRow.o_totalprice,'$999G999G999D99')),14));
    end if;
    --
    previousCustomer := currentRow.c_custkey;
  end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line(null);
end;
/
```

Comment: That did not work as it really messed up my output. But thanks for showing me that by changing the sequence, I could alter the sorting process. Still quite new to oracle sql at the moment. Thx for the help tho